# FileExistsError in mkdir and makedirs in Python even if directory doesn't exist

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to create two directories: `foo1` and `foo2`.
There is nothing named `foo1` in the current directory, **but there is a file named** `foo2`.

These are the results:

```
user@workstation:~/Desktop/newfolder$ ls
foo2
user@workstation:~/Desktop/newfolder$ file foo2
foo2: ASCII text
-----
>>> os.mkdir('foo1')
>>> os.mkdir('foo2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo2'
>>> os.makedirs('foo2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/janreggie/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo2'
```

Now, is there a way to create a directory `foo2` while there is a file `foo2`?

Comment: It depends on your OS, but most of them forbid such behavior.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22447/16669

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not a Python issue. This is an Operating System constraint. Are you working with Windows? As piRSquared stated before, you can't have two entities with same name in same directory. Once OS will make a difference between files and directories, it will allow Python to create a subdirectory with the same name than any already existing file. Furthermore, the 'try-except' proposal from piRSquared is a correct way to inform of issue while not stopping processing.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a `try`/`except`

```
def my_mkdir(dir):
    try:
        os.mkdir(dir)
    except:
        pass
```

Then use `my_mkdir('foo1')` and `my_mkdir('foo2')`

Comment: That doesn't work. I tried it myself.

Besides, it just simply does the `mkdir()` function, but with "if it fails, just pass it", meaning it doesn't do anything to address the issue of `mkdir()`.

Comment: I missed the question part of your question. Sorry about that. The answer is no. You can't have a directory and file with same name in same directory. A directory is just a file itself. That's the same as asking if you can have two files with the same name in the same directory. That answer is no also as that is the whole point of a file system.